# How to make celery root dish without parmesan?

Tags: substitutions, celery, root, parmesan

I've used a recipe before (can't find it anymore, sorry) where I steamed sticks of celery root. The ingredients I remember are garlic (whole cloves steamed together with the celery), probably a small amount of water or vegetable broth and butter - or perhaps olive oil - (for the steaming) and Parmesan sprinkled over in the end. After steaming in a small amount of liquid covered with parchment until tender the vegetables were removed and the resulting broth cooked until thick and used as a glace.

My question is, what could I do to be able to cook this if I don't have Parmesan. As the dish does have a strong flavour on its own I think it would be OK but is there perhaps something (nondairy, non-meat, not from a special shop) I could substitute with? I am concerned with what would complement the tastes, not necessarily finding replica Parmesan taste in another product.
I want this to taste great, not just be edible!
Thanks

Comment: You should inquire further into the degree of allergy. Most lactose intolerant people can tolerate hard cheese and butter remarkably well, even without symptoms; it is fresh milk, cream, ice cream, and partly cultured products like yoghurt and fresh cheeses (cream cheese, quark) which produce a reaction (which can again range from slight gas production to strong cramps).

Comment: OK I will this afternoon!

Comment: My friend is apparently eating everything now so... discussion changed

Comment: Look at the discussion in this question (http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/whats-a-good-nondairy-substitute-for-parmesan-grana-padano-as-a-salad-topper/8203#8203) for an analysis of how to substitute for Parmesan in general. The main issue for your recipe would be the issue of texture.

Answer (score 1):

I find celeriac loves coriander -seed and especially root. White pepper, horseradish or perhaps mustard oil or powder can be added by a smidge for a hint of warmth.

This is still a mild side-dish, ya for something else flavorful on the plate?
I love serving pumpkin at the same meal 'cause they bring out the best in each other... IMHO.